# Backpropagation Neural Network doesn't learn properly

Tags: c++, machine-learning, backpropagation

I'm coding neural network and I have trouble with understanding and coding Backpropagation, but it doesn't learn properly. I don't know where is problem in my Backpropagation function.

This is my error function  `L = plogq + (1−p)log(1−q)`

And my activation function is `f(x)=1/(1+e^(-x))`

I'm trying on easy problem `x > y` which doesn't really need multilayer perceptron.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
const double ETA=0.001;
const double EPS=0.000001;
const bool OUTPUT=true;
typedef function<double(vector<double>, vector<double>)> func;
double scalar_product(vector<double> a, vector<double> b)
{
    assert(a.size() == b.size());
    double ret = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
    {
        ret += a[i] * b[i];
    }
    return ret;
}
class Perceptron
{
public:
    int n;
    double val,der;
    double delta;
    vector<int> next;
    vector<double> w;
    function<double(vector<double>, vector<double>)> h;
    function<double(vector<double>, vector<double>)> d;

    Perceptron(int n,func h,func d):n(n),h(h),d(d)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<n+1; i++)
            w.push_back(1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX);
    }
    double calc(vector<double> x)
    {
        val=h(w,x);
        der=d(w,x);
        return val;
    }
};
class NeuralNetwork
{
public:
    int inputLayer,hiddenLayer,outputLayer;
    vector<Perceptron> inputNeurons;
    vector<Perceptron> hiddenNeurons;
    vector<Perceptron> outputNeurons;
    NeuralNetwork(int in,int hid,int out)
    {
        inputLayer=in;
        hiddenLayer=hid;
        outputLayer=out;

        auto logistic = [] (vector<double> w, vector<double> x) -> double
        {
            x.push_back(1.0);
            return 1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-scalar_product(w, x)));
        };
        auto d_logistic = [logistic] (vector<double> w, vector<double> x) -> double
        {
            double lst = logistic(w, x);
            return lst * (1.0 - lst);
        };

        auto input = [] (vector<double> w, vector<double> x) -> double
        {
            return x[0];
        };
        auto d_input = [] (vector<double> w, vector<double> x) -> double
        {
            return 1.0;
        };

        auto ident = [] (vector<double> w, vector<double> x) -> double
        {
            x.push_back(1.0);
            return scalar_product(w, x);
        };
        auto d_ident = [] (vector<double> w, vector<double> x) -> double
        {
            return 1.0;
        };

        for(int i=0; i<inputLayer; i++)
            inputNeurons.push_back(Perceptron(1,input,d_input));
        if(OUTPUT)cout<<"Created "<<inputLayer<<" input neurons."<<endl;
        for(int i=0; i<hiddenLayer; i++)
            hiddenNeurons.push_back(Perceptron(inputLayer,logistic,d_logistic));
        if(OUTPUT)cout<<"Created "<<hiddenLayer<<" hidden neurons."<<endl;
        for(int i=0; i<outputLayer; i++)
            outputNeurons.push_back(Perceptron(hiddenLayer,logistic,d_logistic));
        if(OUTPUT)cout<<"Created "<<outputLayer<<" output neurons."<<endl;

    }
    vector<double> feedForward(vector<double> x)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<inputLayer; i++)
            inputNeurons[i].calc({x[i]});
        vector<double> inputLayerOut;
        for(int i=0; i<inputLayer; i++)
            inputLayerOut.push_back(inputNeurons[i].val);

        for(int i=0; i<hiddenLayer; i++)
            hiddenNeurons[i].calc(inputLayerOut);
        vector<double> hiddenLayerOut;
        for(int i=0; i<hiddenLayer; i++)
            hiddenLayerOut.push_back(hiddenNeurons[i].val);

        for(int i=0; i<outputLayer; i++)
            outputNeurons[i].calc(hiddenLayerOut);
        vector<double> outputLayerOut;
        for(int i=0; i<outputLayer; i++)
            outputLayerOut.push_back(outputNeurons[i].val);
        return outputLayerOut;
    }
    void backPropagation(vector<vector<double> > x, vector<vector<double> > y, int max_steps)
    {
        double diff;
        do
        {
            diff=0.0;
            for(int t=0; t<x.size(); t++)
            {
                vector<double> out=feedForward(x[t]);
                for(int i=0; i<outputLayer; i++)
                    outputNeurons[i].delta=(y[t][i]-outputNeurons[i].val);
                for(int i=0; i<hiddenLayer; i++)
                {
                    double sum=0.0;
                    for(int j=0; j<outputLayer; j++)
                        sum+=outputNeurons[j].delta*hiddenNeurons[i].w[j];
                    hiddenNeurons[i].delta=hiddenNeurons[i].der*sum;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<outputLayer; i++)
            {
                for (int j=0; j<outputNeurons[i].w.size(); j++)
                {
                    double z = (j < outputNeurons[i].n) ? hiddenNeurons[j].val : 1.0;
                    double curr = ETA * outputNeurons[i].delta * z;
                    outputNeurons[i].w[j] += curr;
                    diff += curr * curr;
                }
            }
            for(int i=0; i<hiddenLayer; i++)
            {
                for (int j=0; j<hiddenNeurons[i].w.size(); j++)
                {
                    double z = (j < hiddenNeurons[i].n) ? inputNeurons[j].val : 1.0;
                    double curr = ETA * hiddenNeurons[i].delta * z;
                    hiddenNeurons[i].w[j] += curr;
                    diff += curr * curr;
                }
            }
            if(OUTPUT&&max_steps%100==0)cout<<"Current diff: "<<diff<<endl;
        }
        while(diff>EPS&&max_steps--);
    }

};

int main()
{
    //srand(time(NULL));
    NeuralNetwork nn=NeuralNetwork(2,5,1);
    vector<vector<double> > trainingInput;
    vector<vector<double> > trainingOutput;
    trainingInput.resize(100);
    trainingOutput.resize(100);
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        int x=rand()%100;
        int y=rand()%100;
        trainingInput[i].push_back(x);
        trainingInput[i].push_back(y);
        trainingOutput[i].push_back(x>y?1:0);
    }
    nn.backPropagation(trainingInput,trainingOutput,10000);
    while(true)
    {
        int x,y;
        cin>>x>>y;
        cout<<nn.feedForward({x,y})[0]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But, problem is because I don't understand backpropagination completely.

Comment: I'm not sure is my formulas correct.

Comment: I have posted whole code only for understanding notions, problem is somewhere in backPropagation function.

Comment: Well, as mentioned use the debugger, step at that point and check your current variable values-

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ "Don't ask questions" isn't useful advice on a site devoted to asking questions.

Comment: But I don't understand completely mathematical background and I can't know what variable values are ok, and what are not.

Comment: Off topic: The usual commentary. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: offtopic: Well this is my habit from competitive programming skills.

Comment: Weights and the activation function's input can be negative, even when the final activation is not.  So when you initialize your weights, half the possible range should be negative. Also, I don't like the big initial weights with a mean absolute value of 0.5.  This just  puts most initial activations on one of the extremes of the sigmoid, saturated at 0 or 1, and with a derivative somewhere close to zero -- so updates will change weights very little, or not at all.  Your initial weights, with typical inputs, should produce activations between 0.1 and 0.9, so scale them down.

Answer (score 1):

For backpropagation code, the key point is to calculate the gradient correctly. You can check the gradient by computing a numerical approximation and comparing that. A numerical approximation to the gradient is just `(F(x; w + dw) - F(x; w))/dw` where `x` is an input vector (could be anything, doesn't matter for this purpose), `w` is one of the weights or biases, and `dw` is a small number (e.g. 1e-4). For each weight and bias, compute that difference, then compare the vector of approximations to whatever you are getting from your code. They should be approximately the same, and should get closer as you make `dw` smaller.

Comment: (F(x; w + dw) - F(x; w))/dw is derivate definiton. I don't know where to apply this and where from code?

Comment: Do you have some material which describe backpropagination in good way?

Comment: Take a look at, say, "Pattern Recognition and Neural Networks" by Brian Ripley, and/or "Elements of Statistical Learning" by Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman.